# SELECT Without wildcard returns 0 rows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

For some reason my SELECT query with an AND clause is exhibiting some odd behaviour. It returns zero rows, when I know for a fact that there are matches. If I remove either of the clauses, it works. Or, the strangest part, if I add a wildcard to the end of the string to match, it returns the expected results. Even though there doesn't appear to be any extra bytes at the end of the column data.

A demonstration:

```
SELECT HEX(type),
       type,
       category 
  FROM cats 
 WHERE `category` = 10 AND 
       `type` LIKE "Furry";

Empty set (0.07 sec)
```

but

```
SELECT HEX(type),type,category FROM cats WHERE `type` LIKE "Furry";
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| HEX(type)                        | type                   | category |
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| 4675727279                       | Furry                  |       10 |
...
```

And

```
SELECT HEX(type),type,category FROM cats WHERE `category`=10 AND `type` LIKE "Furry%";
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| HEX(type)                        | type                   | category |
+----------------------------------+------------------------+----------+
| 4675727279                       | Furry                  |       10 |
...
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could it be that it is trying to use a corrupt index? Try this please: `optimize table cats` then re-run the queries.

Comment: It sounds like there might be a special character or space that is at the end of the data that's not being displayed.

Comment: @JehadKeriaki I'm trying this, but it could take a while. There are a lot of "cats" in the table.

Comment: @SQLDataInTraining Whould that not show in the HEX(type) column?

Comment: @JehadKeriaki `optimize table cats` fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: @LifeOfRPi great. I will add it as an answer, hoping it will be useful for others with similar issues.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- want to see Engine, datatypes, collations, indexes, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the execution plan, and the data distribution, MySQL would decide to scan the table or one of the indexes to get the required data.

If the data is to be read from an index, and the index is corrupted, it is possible that no data or wrong data is returned.

Optimizing the table will rebuild the table and its indexes. So, if an index was corrupted, it will be fixed after the optimization.

HTH

Comment: how do you know if index is corrupted?